# Odoo auto-fill fields when created from other form

Tags: python, odoo, field, odoo-8

Any idea how I can fill in some fields on the product page when I quick create this from a Sales Order. These fields are based on the Sales Order (name and customer). Do I need to pass them with context?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you want and what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with `context`. In your `sale.order.line` XML views, you have a `Many2one` field named `product_id` (it points to `product.product` model).

You have to specify the default value you want for each `product.product` field, extracting the value for the fields of the current view (`sale.order.line`):

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="context">{'default_field_1': field_1, 'default_field_2': field_2}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Where `default_field_1` and `default_field_2` are fields of the `product.product` model, and `field_1` and `field_2` are fields of `sale.order.line` model.

Example:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="context">{'default_name': name}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

In the above case, when you create a new product (clicking on the create option of the dropdown of the `Many2one` field `product_id`) from `sale.order.line` tree or form view, the `product.product` form would be opened with the `name` field automatically filled in with the name of the current sale order line.